# $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ a not empty, open interval and $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ convex function.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ a not empty, open interval and  $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ convex function.

Show that, $f$ is in every point in $I$ differentiable from the left and differentiable from the right, that the one-sided derivations $f'_+, f'_-:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ growing monotonously and $\forall x_0\in I$: $f'_-(x_0)\le f'_+(x_0)$.

And show that you can infer from that: $f$ is continuous and in differentiable in every point except in countless many

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $\forall \ (x,y,z) \in I^3, \ x<y<z \implies \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}≤ \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}≤\frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y} $